# Can enumerated lists be centred?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, enumerate

For enumerated list such as:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\end{enumerate}
```

the `center` and `centering` commands don't seem to work, and the list sticks to the left hand side of the page. Is it possible to centre such a list, or would I have to use something other than `enumerate`?

Comment: Have you tried using a minipage or box?

Comment: do you want to centre the block as a whole or to centre each item separately (both are possible)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the block as a whole

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can center the list in a `minipage` but rather than have to guess a width for the minipage you can use the `varwidth` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}
\centering

X\dotfill X

\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate}
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\end{enumerate}
\end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, I've added a reference after the list, to the bottom right using `\hfill`, so I've found that `center` works better than `centering`.