# Centering list issue with Enumerate+Hyperref+Varwidth

Tags: horizontal-alignment, hyperref, lists, varwidth

I want to center an enumerated list so i've tried to use the answer [of this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107527/can-enumerated-lists-be-centred/107533#107533) given by the Great David Carlisle.
But using `hyperref`, `varwidth` and `enumerate` (in any order in the preamble) cause a failure: the list (which I wish to be centered) is left aligned.

The minipage is due to my real situation.

I would be very grateful if someone could provide a fix and some explanations.

The mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering

\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}% it's OK : "aaa" is centered
aaa
\end{varwidth}

\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}% Ouch ! the list is left aligned
\begin{enumerate}
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\end{enumerate}
\end{varwidth}

\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Thanks

P.S. Sorry for the bad English, I do my best.

Comment: `varwidth` is unable to do its working when `hyperref` is loaded and a list is involved.

Comment: The `Great David Carlisle`;-)

Comment: @egreg : thanks for the answer. I know you're really busy (on this site at least) but could you explain why is not possible if you have the time (and if you want !)

Comment: @sbm I'm not sure of the reason, but apparently the work done by `hyperref` in order to provide hyperlinks to items hinders the job `varwidth` wants to perform. Do you need hyperlinks to the items?

Comment: @egreg : no i don't need hyperref for the items of the list i try to center. But i use hyperef a lot for the rest of my doc. Thanks a lot for your work on this site which i use a lot.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I hope the smiley signals agreement not incredulity!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Full agreement of course. It was a smile of amusement only :D