# Hyperref package affects enumerate inside varwidth

Tags: hyperref, enumerate, itemize, varwidth

In the following example, why does `hyperref` package affect `enumerate` (but not `itemize`) inside `varwidth` environment? Is it a bug?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{hyperref} % removing it solves the problem 

\begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item One
    \item Two
  \end{itemize}
\end{varwidth}}

\fbox{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item One
    \item Two
  \end{enumerate}
\end{varwidth}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Remark**: The result is wrong when I compile the code with PDFLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, but it is correct with XeLaTeX.

Comment: `Package varwidth Warning: Failed to reprocess entire contents on input line 20.`

Comment: well it is known, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297293/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Seems a very old bug. Are there any workarounds for it that I can tell users of my package?

Comment: I will take a look in the afternoon. A work around is to disable anchors with `\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}\csname measuring@true\endcsname`

Comment: It works. Thanks!

Comment: There is an issue in the package repository: https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/204

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`varwidth` has a problem if there is a primitive creating a whatsits at the begin of a paragraph.

`varwidth` contains code (`\@vwid@wrap`) for this case and uses it to handle `\special` and `\pdfliteral` so e.g. `\colors` works (but only in xelatex and pdflatex, lualatex fails).

But here the underlying primitive is `\pdfdest` and this fails.

The following should work. I will probably add such a configuration point to hyperref so that varwidth can use it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varwidth,etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref,color}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\hyper@configure@raisedlink@vmode[1]{#1}
\patchcmd\Hy@raisedlink{\ifvmode #1}{\ifvmode \hyper@configure@raisedlink@vmode{#1}}{}{\fail}
\appto\@vwid@setup{\let\hyper@configure@raisedlink@vmode\@vwid@wrap}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
abc

\fbox{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item One
    \item Two
  \end{enumerate}
\end{varwidth}}

\end{document}
```